# Get data from mongodb with express and display in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, express, mern

I have code that works with html forms, express, and mongodb which is: server.js:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    db.collection('miscData').find().toArray((err, result) => {
        if (err) return console.log(err)
        res.render('index.ejs', { miscData: result })
    })

})
```

and in the index.ejs file:

```
<ul class="quotes">
        <% for(var i=0; i<miscData.length; i++) {%>
            <li class="quote">
                <span>favorite number: <%= miscData[i].favoriteNumber %></span>
                <span>num id: <%= miscData[i]._id %></span>
            </li>
            <% console.log(miscData) %>
                <% } %>
    </ul>
```

This retrieves the data from the database and displays it to the user. I wanted to implement in React.
React Version:

app.js:

```
function App() {

  const [getBasic, setGetBasic] = useState()

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('/')
    .then(res => setGetBasic(res.data))
  }, [])


  return (
    <div className="App">
      <p>{getBasic}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

server.js:
first I tried this:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  db.collection('miscData').find().toArray((err, result) => {
      if (err) return console.log(err)
      res.render('index', { miscData: result })
  })
})
```

Which made the output a strange html file: (this is `getBasic`):

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html lang="en"> <head> <meta charset="utf-8" /> <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" /> <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" /> <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" /> <meta name="description" content="Web site created using create-react-app" /> <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/logo192.png" /> <!-- manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is installed on a user's mobile device or desktop. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/ --> <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json" /> <!-- Notice the use of in the tags above. It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build. Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML. Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "/favicon.ico" will work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL. Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`. --> <title>React App</title> <script defer src="/static/js/bundle.js"></script></head> <body> <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript> <div id="root"></div> <!-- This HTML file is a template. If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page. You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file. The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag. To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`. To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`. --> </body> </html>
```

I thought maybe I needed to use `res.send(App.js, {miscData: result})` instead of `res.render`, however I ended up with the same result.

Edit:

currently app.js:

```
function App() {

  const [getBasic, setGetBasic] = useState()

  useEffect(async () => {
    await axios.get('http://localhost:3001/api')
      .then(res => setGetBasic(res.data))
  }, [])


  return (
    <div className="App">
      <p>{getBasic}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Server.js:

```
app.get('/api', (req, res) => {
    db.collection('miscData').find().toArray((err, result) => {
        if (err) return console.log(err)
        res.json({ miscData: result })
    })

})
```

edit 2 update:

I moved the async and await outside to a seperate function and then have that function get called in useEffect due to react warnings. When I `console.log(getBasic)` I am getting undefined 2-4 times and then getting an object. Here is a picture of the console.log of it. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4O7A.png)

I tried to `console.log(getBasic[0])` to get the first one which said it cannot do that for undefined and `console.log(getBasic.blogTitle)` and `console.log(getBasic.miscData)` and all of which did not work. I tried mapping through getBasic however I get an error because getBasic is undefined (which is only the case some of the time, I thought that async await fixed that). I also added access-control-allow-origin in the api call under server.js

here is my code now:

app.js

```
function App() {

  const [getBasic, setGetBasic] = useState()


  async function fetchData() {
    await axios.get('http://localhost:3001/api')
    .then(result => setGetBasic(result.data))
    
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData()
  }, [])

  

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <p>{console.log(getBasic)}</p>
      <p>{console.log(`blog title ${getBasic}`)}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

server.js:

```
app.get('/api', (req, res) => {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:3000');
  res.header(
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
    'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept'
  );
  db.collection('miscData').find().toArray((err, result) => {
      if (err) return console.log(err)
      res.json({ miscData: result })
  })
})
```

Comment: are you running server and client on different PORTS?

Comment: yes port 3000 for client and 3001 for server, and I have `"proxy": "http://localhost:3001",` in package.json for react

Comment: the path `/` uses the current host which is likely your react development environment, provide the correct hostname in your axios call for example `http://localhost:3001` that leads to your backend

Comment: instead of res.send(App.js, {miscData: result}) use res.send({miscData: result}). Only send the data no need to redirect.

Comment: are you saying `  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('/')
    .then(res => setGetBasic(res.data))
  }, [])` needs to be `  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('http://localhost:8080')
    .then(res => setGetBasic(res.data))
  }, [])` ?

Comment: You can simply return data from server using
`res.json({miscData:result})`

Comment: I am still getting the same result using `res.json({miscData:result})` in server.js

Comment: Unless you meant I need to put res.json({miscData: result}) in the app.js?

Comment: Change the route in GET request on server `app.get("/api")` and in react useEffect inside axios `await axios.get("/api")`

Comment: I tried implementing each of the comments on my desktop I was getting still the html file returned but currently on my mac I am now getting `react-dom.development.js:14757 Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {miscData}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.` Where can I change this to an array at?

Comment: I just updated the original post with what I have changed in the code based on the changes I have made based on the comments.